# Display records from database

Tags: php, mysql, input, record

I'm trying to display some information stored in MySQL comments table to an input but I'm having issues with that. Input named `enterComment` inserts data to my DB and I want it to redirect back to `showComment` input.

HTML:

```
form action='takedata.php' method='POST'>
            <input type='text' id='enterComment' name='enterComment' width='400px' placeholder='Write a comment...'>
            <input type='submit' id='combuton' name='comButon' value='Comment!'>
            <input type='text' id='showComment' name='showComment'>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php include "mysql.php"; ?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['comButon'])){
        $enterComment = strip_tags($_POST['enterComment']);
            if($enterComment){
                $addComment = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(comment) VALUES('$enterComment')");
                if($addComment==1)
                    //INSERT INTO showComment input;
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where is code of your VIEW?

Comment: Please read article of how to make connection with the database using PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

try this, and use mysqli instead of mysql

```
include "dbconnect.php"; 
if (isset($_POST['comButon'])){
        $enterComment = strip_tags($_POST['enterComment']);
        if($enterComment){
            $addComment = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO comments(comment) VALUES('$enterComment')");
            if($addComment) {
                $sql = "select comment from comments order by id desc limit 1";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['comment']; ?>">
                <?php }
            }

        } 
}
```

your form

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
            <input type='text' id='enterComment' name='enterComment' width='400px' placeholder='Write a comment...'>
            <input type='submit' id='combuton' name='comButon' value='Comment!'>
            <?php if(!isset($_POST['comButon'])) { ?>
                 <input type="text" value="">
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, Idk why the input where it supposed to push the comments just disappeared.